# jbehave click link within

Tags: bdd, jbehave

Is there any function similar to [click_link_within](http://rdoc.info/github/brynary/webrat/master/Webrat/Session#click_link_within-instance_method) in jbehave?

I want an easy way to click a link which is selected by it's text within a certain area on the page.

Comment: fyi: driver.findElement(By.id(container))
   .findElement(By.linkText(linkText))
   .click();

Answer (score 0):

JBehave is a framework to drive tests based on BDD syntax which promotes communcation with stakeholders. It can be translated to any form of action to any type of application but this has to be done by integrating JBehave with the underlying technical framework.

So the answer is no, not automatically. And yes, you are totally free to integrate with any technical framework you choose.

Study the examples by cloning the git repo or read more of the documentation on jbehave.org.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I was referring to the Web libraries in Jbehave http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/javadoc/web-selenium/index.html